# Error 404 on every page of category base url in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I've got next issue while trying to learn Wordpress CMS.
This is my Settings->Permalinks page:
Post name: local.com/%postname%/
Category base: news

So, */news/* working correctly, but */news/page/{any page number}* goes to 404 error.
Also, urls like */news/example/* and */news/example/page/{any page number}* are working correctly. If I remove news from "Category base", then there is no 404 error, but this links (*/news/example/*) not working.

I'm trying to add a function on "pre_get_posts" where I set 'post_per_page' parameter - no result. Also I've clicked on Save button in Permalinks page. This is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I see, that there are a lot of people with similar issue, but their solutions didn't help me. Are there any other solutions or debug ways of this problem?